# How to set environment variables for system extension

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, networkextension, macos-system-extension

I knew the LSEnvironment is for defining environment variables to be set before launching the App.

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
<key>PATH</key>
<string>...</string>
</dict>
```

How about system extension? How can I set some environment variables before the system extension running? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the purpose of these? If you're going to have env var values hard coded in a plist, they may as well just be hard coded in your app's source, no?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I build an App with Asan, in order to bypass the crash, I have to run with environment variable ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0